# Oracle XE 11g Table not correctly displayed

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I'm new to Oracle and I've installed Oracle Express Edition 11g on my laptop running Windows 8 operating system. I'd been told that the Enterprise Edition, which is not of course free, contains a predefined table called EMP. I've seen the table on my college computer. But the XE didn't come with it. So I googled it a found a script(.sql script) which contains all the predefined tables. I imported them using the @*filepath/filename.sql*. But when I used the

```
    select * from emp;
```

it displayed the table incorrectly. I don't mean the records of the table, but the formatting of the table.

Now look at the DEPTNO and EMPNO columns.

http://postimage.org/image/sut6axlhr/

The code in the sql script was following

```
--
-- Copyright (c) Oracle Corporation 1988, 1999.  All Rights Reserved.
--
--  NAME
--    demobld.sql
--
-- DESCRIPTION
--   This script creates the SQL*Plus demonstration tables in the
--   current schema.  It should be STARTed by each user wishing to
--   access the tables.  To remove the tables use the demodrop.sql
--   script.
--
--  USAGE
--       SQL> START demobld.sql
--
--

SET TERMOUT ON
PROMPT Building demonstration tables.  Please wait.
SET TERMOUT OFF

CREATE TABLE BONUS
        (ENAME VARCHAR2(10),
         JOB   VARCHAR2(9),
         SAL   NUMBER,
         COMM  NUMBER);

CREATE TABLE EMP
       (EMPNO NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
        ENAME VARCHAR2(10),
        JOB VARCHAR2(9),
        MGR NUMBER(4),
        HIREDATE DATE,
        SAL NUMBER(7, 2),
        COMM NUMBER(7, 2),
        DEPTNO NUMBER(2));

INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7369, 'SMITH',  'CLERK',     7902,
        TO_DATE('17-DEC-1980', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),  800, NULL, 20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7499, 'ALLEN',  'SALESMAN',  7698,
        TO_DATE('20-FEB-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1600,  300, 30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7521, 'WARD',   'SALESMAN',  7698,
        TO_DATE('22-FEB-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1250,  500, 30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7566, 'JONES',  'MANAGER',   7839,
        TO_DATE('2-APR-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),  2975, NULL, 20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7654, 'MARTIN', 'SALESMAN',  7698,
        TO_DATE('28-SEP-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1250, 1400, 30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7698, 'BLAKE',  'MANAGER',   7839,
        TO_DATE('1-MAY-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),  2850, NULL, 30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7782, 'CLARK',  'MANAGER',   7839,
        TO_DATE('9-JUN-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),  2450, NULL, 10);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7788, 'SCOTT',  'ANALYST',   7566,
        TO_DATE('09-DEC-1982', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 3000, NULL, 20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7839, 'KING',   'PRESIDENT', NULL,
        TO_DATE('17-NOV-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 5000, NULL, 10);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7844, 'TURNER', 'SALESMAN',  7698,
        TO_DATE('8-SEP-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),  1500, NULL, 30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7876, 'ADAMS',  'CLERK',     7788,
        TO_DATE('12-JAN-1983', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1100, NULL, 20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7900, 'JAMES',  'CLERK',     7698,
        TO_DATE('3-DEC-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),   950, NULL, 30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7902, 'FORD',   'ANALYST',   7566,
        TO_DATE('3-DEC-1981', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),  3000, NULL, 20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
        (7934, 'MILLER', 'CLERK',     7782,
        TO_DATE('23-JAN-1982', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1300, NULL, 10);

CREATE TABLE DEPT
       (DEPTNO NUMBER(2),
        DNAME VARCHAR2(14),
        LOC VARCHAR2(13) );

INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES (10, 'ACCOUNTING', 'NEW YORK');
INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES (20, 'RESEARCH',   'DALLAS');
INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES (30, 'SALES',      'CHICAGO');
INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES (40, 'OPERATIONS', 'BOSTON');

CREATE TABLE SALGRADE
        (GRADE NUMBER,
         LOSAL NUMBER,
         HISAL NUMBER);

INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (1,  700, 1200);
INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (2, 1201, 1400);
INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (3, 1401, 2000);
INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (4, 2001, 3000);
INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (5, 3001, 9999);

COMMIT;

SET TERMOUT ON
PROMPT Demonstration table build is complete.
```

I used the *ed* command to use notepad and did paste the code and saved it. Then I used the *run* command to import the table.
Now my problem is to fix this thing. Thanks in advance. :)
And it is my first post in any forum, so sorry if I didn't post it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your linesize is too small. run this in sql*plus:

```
set linesize 200
```

before you select from the table

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. But there is another problem. There are two column names getting displayed. Two tables.   <http://tinypic.com/r/10dbk87/6>

Comment: yes this is PAGESIZE. ie `set pagesize 2000` will resolve it (this is the setting to determine how many lines of output occur before the column names are repeated).  i recommend you read up on sql*plus here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_six.htm#SQPUG016

Comment: @user2040026 - perhaps a link to the [various options you can set](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm) would be useful; specifically [`LINESIZE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#i2678481) and [`PAGESIZE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#i2699247). And some general [formatting info](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_six.htm) that's aimed more at reports than straight queries, but might be helpful at some point.

Comment: @AlexPoole yep i provided that in the comment followup

Comment: Ah, sorry, maybe you edited to add that and I didn't see the update.

Comment: The link is just so much helpful. Thanks a lot.